# htaccess URL rewrite with PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, .htaccess

**My Question is:** How can I show it **http://localhost/jakir1/banner2/test.php/title-3** instead of **http://localhost/jakir1/banner2/test.php?slug=title-3**

When i click

1. title 1
2. title 2
3. title 3

Its Showed Output

**Here is My Code:**

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
     Product Name 
   </td>
    <td>
    Description 
   </td>
   </tr>
   <?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM marchant_item ORDER BY id DESC";
         $display =  mysqli_query($db, $sql);
         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($display)) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="test.php?slug=<?php echo $row['slug']; ?>"><?php echo $row['item_name']; ?></a></td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row['description']; ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
   <?php      }
    ?>
</table>

<?php
if (isset($_GET['slug'])) {
$data = $_GET['slug'];
?>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
     Product Name 
   </td>
    <td>
    category
   </td>
   </tr>
   <?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM marchant_item WHERE slug ='$data'";
         $display =  mysqli_query($db, $sql);
         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($display)) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['item_name']; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row['category']; ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
   <?php      }
    ?>

</table>
<?php
}
?>
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: I don't really understand your question. The URL with the get argument (`.../test.php?slug=title-3`) is exactly what you reate with your php code. If you do not want that but some other URL, then just output another URL. What is the question here?

Answer (score 0):

write this line in your .htaccess file--
RewriteRule ^test/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ test.php?slug=$1 [NC]

update your code with

```html
<td><a href="test/<?php echo $row['slug']; ?>"><?php echo $row['item_name']; ?></a></td>
```

and you get
http://localhost/jakir1/banner2/test/title-3